# Subset items in list of list based on indices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like the following:

```
test = [['hi', 'hi2'], ['bye', 'bye2', 'by3']]
```

and would like to subset it based on another list of lists with the desired indices in it:

```
indices = [[0], [0, 2]]
```

For a normal list of values and list of indices, it is easy to do:

```
[1d_list[i] for i in 1d_indices]
```

So I tried something similar for this list of lists, but it is not working

```
[[[t[i] for i in ii] for t in test] for ii in indices]
```

Could you please advise what is wrong?

The desired output for this part is

```
test_out = [['hi'], ['bye', 'by3']]
```

Also, how can I select the exact inverse of what is in `indices`?

For example, desired output would be:

```
test_out_2 = [['hi2'], ['bye2']]
```

Thanks!
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` with `enumerate`:

```
test = [['hi', 'hi2'], ['bye', 'bye2', 'by3']]
indices = [[0], [0, 2]] 
new_test = [[a for i, a in enumerate(c) if i in b] for c, b in zip(test, indices)]
```

Output:

```
[['hi'], ['bye', 'by3']]
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining this a bit further please?

Comment: @JackArnestad Glad to help! `zip` pairs the elements of the lists passed to it horizontally. Thus, the paring `['hi', 'hi2'] -> [0]` and `['bye', 'bye2', 'by3'] -> [0, 2]` is created. `enumerate` loops over the first element of the pairing, while also generating the current index of iteration. Then, the code checks if the index exists in the second pairing element. If so, the value is added to the sublist currently being created.